# What is the best practice to remove C structs end padding?

Tags: c++, c, struct, c++11

What is the best way to make a non-packed non-padded struct in C or C++? The goal is:

```
typedef struct {
    char first[3]; //padded to 8 because next type has size 8
    double second;
    char third;
} SomeStruct;

but do something to make sizeof(SomeStruct) be equal 17;
```

The structure is defined by external library specification. I have a 2 decisions:

1)

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)

typedef struct {
    char first[3];
        char unused[5]; // Manual padding of second field.
    double second;
    char third;
} SomeStruct;

#pragma pack (pop)
```

2) Using the first variant of declaration, but write `(int)(&((SomeStruct*)0)->third) + sizeof(((SomeStruct*)0)->third)` instead of `sizeof(SomeStruct)` when serializing data. I don't need to serialize arrays of such structs, so can do that.

But both of them are dirty hacks. Is there a standard approach of removing the structs padding in C?

Comment: If `double` requires 8 byte alignment, then `sizeof(SomeStruct)` will not be 17, it will be 24.  There needs to be padding at the end of the struct to ensure that contiguous array elements are correctly aligned.

Comment: Option 3) Leave your initial struct as it is. It's inherently non-portable in that the representation and alignment requirements of double may be different on other systems, so you already rely on your compiler conforming to a specific ABI. This isn't made any worse by relying on the compiler-generated padding.

Comment: If an external library defines this struct it will depend on its layout as is. Changing anything about it will make it incompatible with this library. Also, if `sizeof(SomeStruct)` is 17 I'd quickly find a compiler from some who knows what he is doing! If there is padding there are alignment constraints and the size should be a multiple of the required alignment.

Comment: I know, this C struct has a size 24. And I want to trim them to 17. The library is written on Pascal, which is not adding a padding at the end of structures by-default.

Comment: @ognev.p Could you include the Pascal definition of the type in your question, and mention which compiler you use? Delphi (which is admittedly definitely not standard Pascal) does include the trailing padding, and gives your record a size of 24.

Comment: @hvd The library is closed-source, and I have not headers, only the specification. It definitely not uses a trailing padding because following data is placed exactly after 17th byte of this structure. I know it's written on Pascal, and somebody say that such behavior is usual for this language, but I'm not sure. My Pascal knowledge remains on a school level.

Comment: @ognev.p Thinking about it some more, your option 2 (except using `offsetof` to make it valid) would be my choice. I'm not sure why you consider it a dirty hack.

Comment: @hvd It became my choice too since 64-bit application is needed. But the problem is a special serialization function instead of simply reinterpretation of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C11 now has the `_Alignas` keyword that could suggest a more narrow alignment of your `double`

```
typedef struct {
    char first[3]; //padded to 8 because next type has size 8
    _Alignas(uint16_t) double second;
    char third;
} SomeStruct;
```

This would do narrower aligment whenever that is possible, that is if the standard operators for `double` on your platform are able to cope with such an alignment. (If not you are screwed anyhow.)

Clang already implements that feature, and other compilers such as gcc already have extensions that come close to it, so you can easily write yourself a wrapper that uses this syntax and is "future proof".

*Edit:* I only saw after posting that your question is also about C++. I think C++1 has the same feature as `alignas`. (C11 has `alignas -> _Alignas` via a macro from a standard header file.)

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is not ideal, but best. I did not found any similar feature in C++0x, but I'm free to compile my code with C++11 compiler.

Comment: @PavelOgnev: under-specifying the alignment of a type is considered an ill-formed C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place it in right order

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s
{
    char first[3];
    char second;
    double third;
};

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", sizeof(struct s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would that help? The struct has to match that of an external library. You don't get to change how the fields are ordered.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I overlooked that it's 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

If the external library specification imposes a size of 17 bytes then your zero'th declaration of SomeStruct is inaccurate.  As James McNellis pointed out in a comment, your version has size 24.  However, we can figure out what you meant.

Your first declaration of SomeStruct accomplishes what you need, because there will be no padding anywhere, and you put in 5 bytes of unused in order to match the external library specification.  Your structure has 17 bytes.  So this looks like your answer.

Your second proposal is unclear because you don't say what your second declaration of SomeStruct is.

It doesn't matter if you use an array of SomeStruct or not.  As James McNellis's comment pointed out, the standard requires that the compiler allow for the possibility of arrays regardless of whether you use some.

(Of course this assumes that double is 8 bytes and your pragma works the way you want, etc.)